# Selection with left join but without showing the Data inside the joined table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, left-join

I've got a table structure with 2 tables

a table person like this:

```
id name etc.   
1  test   
2  smith  
3  shaw
```

and a second table personhist where I document the changes on the names like this: so if someone changed his name because he married or something like this I still got the old name.

```
id personid name    etc.
1     1     oldtest
```

Now I have the following query

```
select * from person p
Left join personhist ph on p.id = ph.personid
where (upper(p.name) = upper('oldtest') or upper(ph.name) like upper('oldtest'));
```

This query will result in the following result

```
id name    id personid name
1  test    1  1        oldtest
```

But I'd like to have only the actual name result. So the question is: is there a way to only show data from the "main" table also if there is a record in the table I join?

Comment: My first thought was 'don't use `select *`', but I'm not quite sure what you want to see - just the `p.name` value? Then why join at all? Maybe you can show your expected result, and some more varied data?

Comment: @AlexPoole I wanna see everything from person but I wanna see the new Name if i search with the oldname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'd like to have only the actuel name result. So the question is is there a way to only show data from the "main" table also if there is a record in the table i join?

Simply do NOT include the columns which you don't want to display. You are using **SELECT *** which is not actually a good thing to do on any production system. You should specify only those column names which are required.

If you really want to display all the columns of one of the table, then , in your query, as you already have an **alias** to the table name, use the same alias to include only that table's columns.

`select p.*` - this will include all columns of table `persons` having alias as `p`.

`select ph.*` - this will include all columns of table `personhist` having alias as `ph`.

To include only selected columns, mention them explicitly. For example -

`select p.id, p.name, ph.personid...`

I guess what you need is -

```
select p.*, ph.personid 
  from person p
 Left join personhist ph on p.id = ph.personid
where (upper(p.name) = upper('oldtest') or upper(ph.name) like upper('oldtest'));
```

But I really doubt what is the purpose to **join** at all when you only need to display is the first table only.

Answer (score 3):

```
select p.*, coalesce(p.name, ph.name)
from person p
Left join personhist ph on p.id = ph.personid
where (upper(p.name) = upper('oldtest') or upper(ph.name) like upper('oldtest'))
```

Comment: Why coalesce? The name is anyway going to be duplicated. The requirement is to display only one name column, which in your query is given by `p.*`, now the coalesce will add another name column which is supposed to be excluded actually.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned (and I won't pile on), you can get the data you need by specifying the columns you actually need in your `SELECT`, e.g.:

```
select p.name from person p
  Left join personhist ph on p.id = ph.personid
 where (upper(p.name) = upper('oldtest') or upper(ph.name) like upper('oldtest'));
```

But I'd like to address a separate issue. Why are you using `LIKE` in this instance? There aren't any wildcards, so you could use `=` just as easily. In addition, you could do the following:

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM person p LEFT JOIN personhist ph
    ON p.id = ph.personid
 WHERE 'OLDTEST' IN ( UPPER(p.name), UPPER(ph.name) );
```

If you are searching for historical names beginning with `OLDTEST` then you would want to do this:

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM person p LEFT JOIN personhist ph
    ON p.id = ph.personid
 WHERE ( UPPER(p.name) = UPPER('oldtest')
      OR UPPER(ph.name) LIKE UPPER('oldtest') || '%');
```

Last, make sure you have a function-based index on `PERSON` (and perhaps one on `PERSONHIST` as well) along the lines of:

```
CREATE INDEX person_name_upper ON person ( UPPER(name) );
```